# how to avoid onCreateView() when swiping in tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have an application with an activity and 3 swipable tabs(fragments). I have some heavily created UI elements inside tabs which take some time to be created and it's ok for the first run, but the views are recreated every time I swipe them.

When I select a tab, the other tab calls onStop() and when I select the previous tab again,onCreateView() is called again and view is repopulated which slows down and blocks UI thread.

What is the correct way to create fragments inside tabs ONCE and avoid recreating their view when swiping between other tabs?

Comment: Are you using ViewPager?

Comment: im using FragmentPagerAdapter, ABS, holoevrywhere and sherlock`s actionbartabs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To add to what CommnosWare stated, if you are using a view pager, you can simply call `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` to keep all three in memory. But if your UI is too heavy, you may notice some jank. So try revising your UI setup code.

Comment: I am using 3 constant tabs and after doing what u proposed, my tabs are very really smooth.I already use worker threads to modify ui.

Answer (score 2):

> I have some heavily created UI elements inside tabs which take some time to be created

If "some time" is more than ~5 milliseconds, your app is broken and needs to be fixed. Use Traceview to determine precisely where you are spending your time, then repair matters so that it takes less time on the main application thread.

> What is the correct way to create fragments inside tabs ONCE and avoid recreating their view when swipping between other tabs?

AFAIK, `FragmentPagerAdapter` should not have the effect that you are describing (though `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will). But, again, if you fix your `onCreateView()` performance issue, even `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will not post a problem.

Comment: its always an honor to get a response from you sir.im using FragmentPagerAdapter  and in my third fragment i use socialize actionbar in bottom of my page to add sharing capabilities to my app but everytime the fragment is selected socialize calls to its servers again and again and shows a progressbar after delaying morethan 5 secs on the UI. Should i not deploy socialize actionbar in fragments onCreateView()?

Comment: @afterburner: "but everytime the fragment is selected socialize calls to its servers again and again and shows a progressbar after delaying morethan 5 secs on the UI" -- sounds like either their API is broken, or you missed some instructions for doing work in the background. "delaying morethan 5 secs on UI" is ghastly and puts you on the edge of an ANR. Also, it's entirely possible that the "socialize actionbar" may not be recreated via `onCreateView()`, but instead is responding to some other `View` lifecycle method that is triggered as the fragment is restored to the screen.

Comment: i had a similar problem and i was using FragmentPagerAdapter but everytime onCreateView() was call the above answer helped. i don't think just using FragmentPagerAdapter solves this issue

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code inside main Fragment/Activity class where TabAdapter declared.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabLayout.getTabCount());
```

The tabLayout and viewPager as follows

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.pager);
```